# RoR - Building a long chain of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Fast questions:

Is possible to build multiple level nested objects? How to do this?

```
@main_object = Object.new
@main_object.build_anotherobject
```

THe questions are: how to build more objects inside theese children objects? And is that a correct thing to do in Rails?

```
@main_object.another.others.build??
```

I don't know how to do that and if this is a good way to achieve multiple level nested objects.
Another question is about handling foreign keys in these nested objects. Some light how to get the correct FK?
I see that i would need to save the objects in a correct order because i need to validate the existence of a row in a parent table and then insert the valid FK inside a child with parent_id.

I could forget a big part of this problem and put many informations inside 1 table instead, but i would like to learn in a professional way, avoiding repeated informations in DB isn't a good point? For example, many people/user lives at same states, same cities, so i'm thinking that i shouldn't save the same strings over and over.

THanks for all attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to assign it to a variable:

```
another_object = @main_object.build_anotherobject
```

And then:

```
another_object.even_more_objects.build
```

Repeat as you need to.

Comment: Will FK be ok? Will Rails know how to set the correct order when saving? If a parent object has a child, and that child has a parent_id, i need to save the parent first and get the ID.

Comment: If you use nested attributes you won't have that problem.